# ZombieJs click event does not fire

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, zombiejs

I'm using ZombieJs for web scraping, what I'm trying to is that when it clicks an element it would display html element of a new page but right now it returns nothing.

```
const Browser = require('zombie');

Browser.visit(("url"), function(error, browser){
   const Search = browser.querySelector("#resultlink_1");
   browser.click(Search);
   console.log(browser.html());
})
```

Comment: Maybe you have to wait for the new page to load?

Comment: By default zombieJs waits till everything is loaded ,but I used setTimeout() and it didn't help

Comment: Can you post a [mcve] containing the target website?

Comment: if I use browser.dump it shows that in history that it was redirected, but when I need to use any element from a new page it says No open window with an HTML document.

Answer (score 0):

Switched from ZmobieJS to Puppeteer and everything works perfectly.